# Yii memcache http

Tags: memcached, php, yii, nginx

Итак необходимо реализовать следующее:

Yii пишет в кеш данные, а далее данные должны быть доступны по адресу:
site.ru/_stat/ключ кеша

В качестве сервера у нас нгинкс, ос: центОс.

<b>Итак:</b>

```
if(!Yii::app()->cache->set($GameProposalModel->proposal_id, 'renderTable('.json_encode($toCache).')'))
```

Я записываю данные в кеш, к примеру ключ будет равен 30 ($GameProposalModel->proposal_id = 30)

Далее идем на нгинкс:

```
   location /_stat {
        set            $memcached_key "$uri?$args";
        memcached_pass 127.0.0.1:11211;
        error_page     404 502 504 = @fallback;
        add_header Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"; 
    }

    location @fallback {

        proxy_pass  http://localhost:9000;
    }
```

Далее я так прикинул, что по ссылку site.ru/_stat/30 я должен получить данные моего кеша. 
Но я получаю только 502 Bad Gateway

Пример из
http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы делаете запрос к сайту site.ru/_stat/30 .
2. Запрос обрабатывает ядро YII - отвечает за это UrlManager согласно настройкам. Также необходимо глянуть что находиться в .htaccess.
3. После работы UrlManager вызывается контроллер, выбирается его действие - передаются в действие все параметры - и действие выполняется.

Поэтому вам нада в контроллере делать действие отвечающие за выборку кэша из memcached и отдачу его клиенту

Comment: нема  .htaccess, у нас тут чистый nginx

Задача на прямую получать данные из кеша по url

Comment: @Ale_x Ну да, при вышеописанном ошибка 502 всегда может случиться, обычное дело.